# Is there a way to define a function with an implementation with a different name?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I have a function in a header that needs to be implemented for the rest of the code to work. Normally I would implement this function in `main.c` after including the header and the linker would clean up the rest.

For example let's say this function is `void foo(bool);` in `foo.h`

If I have another function implemented as part of some other code that matches the task exactly let's say `void bar(bool);` implemented in some `bar.h` and `bar.c`

I would normally go about linking the two by means of including `bar.h` and doing

```c
void foo(bool var) {
    bar(var);
}
```

If there's a lot of these, it's basically just a lot of one line functions for telling the function to call a different one.

Is there a different way to accomplish this?

Comment: Refactor the code to not use `foo` to begin with?

Comment: out of c99 you can put *foo* as an inline function in foo.h. Else *#define foo bar* but that can have bad effects

Comment: I suppose refactoring to use function pointers passed to `foo.c` in some kind of setup function makes some sense as an option.

Comment: yeah, wanted to avoid using `#define` if possible

Comment: you have the tag gcc, is it mandatory for you to be c99 ? without it you can define *foo* inline

Comment: I really think you should take a step back and ask yourself this question: Why do you need both `foo` and `bar`? Besides the name, what is the difference between them? What is the purpose of calling `foo` versus calling `bar`?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you try to accomplish really? -- Since you tagged GCC, you might like to try the linker option `--wrap`.

Comment: @thebusybee mostly just trying to see if there are cleaner ways to implement above-- there's no problem here that's critical

Comment: If you'd consider gcc extensions, there is the `alias` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```c
> void foo(bool var) {
>     bar(var);
> }
> ```

Either the function is global, or it's not.  You have to take a decision; you cannot have both.

If it's just a wrapper in a header, then you can make it static inline:

```c
// bar.h
static inline void foo (bool var)
{
    bar (var);
}
```

It should be clear that you cannot use this together with different definitions / declarations in `foo.h`.

If you just want a function that's called as `foo` to use `bar` as assembly name, then you can use the following C-extension from GNU-C:

```c
// bar.h
void foo (bool) __asm ("bar");
```

This means `bar` will be the assembly name of `foo`. This might avoid an additional call step.  Of course, that also cannot be used with a conflicting definition / declaration of `foo`.  Also notice that you might have to adjust the assembly name, for example i386 platforms usually use a leading `_` (underscore) so that you'd have to use assembly name `_bar`.  And for C++ you'd need the mangled name.

**Bottom line:** In each compilation unit (module) you have to decide what 
implementation of `foo` you want to use, and depending on that, include either `foo.h` or the conflicting `bar.h`.